# How to hide that browser is under SeleniumWebdriver control

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, captcha

Is it any way to do it ? I have automated script which searches through website with captcha and I noticed that if I open this website manually there is only "I'm not a robot" checkbox but when I open it using selenium there are also several puzzles to solve so server must recognize that my browser "is being controlled by automated test software" as Chrome says.
I tried to use incognito mode but it doesn't help.

Comment: Recaptcha knows the difference between your Selenium session that has no previous cookies vs your normal browser where Google knows about you.  The site probably doesn't have any selenium specific detection, though it's easy to do.  Normally, you'll detect no mouse movements (mouseover, mousemove etc) under selenium control.

Answer (score 0):

The main goal of Captcha is: an application to prevent unauthorized access and automated accessing of the websites using any tools/bots. Selenium(or any Automation Tool) cannot read CAPTCHAs.

So, if y can, mock this service in the staging/test environment.
Also, Captcha is an outside service.
It's not necessary to test Captcha behavior, right?

However (as for everything, a hack is available), you can use some software/websites to convert ‘image to text’ (which would be not ‘always’ correct!)

Another thing, we can set cookies for Captcha. The secret key for captcha should be used in this case.